# How to write in a specific column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my attempt.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filenameInp, delimiter =';', usecols=[5],index_col='f')

df.to_csv(filenameOut, mode='a', sep=';', header=False)
```

In this way so far I have not found a way to select the column [6] of the output to paste the column [5]

I know there is another way such as:

Open the two files and merge

But I was hoping to open, read, select and copy a single column of the input file and add it to the second output file.

I do not know if this way would be faster the process just a guess I do not know much about programming

Grateful already

Comment: Could you try explain in different words what you're trying to do? I'm finding it hard to understand the comment right after your code. As far as I can see your code should be able to read column `5` in the input file, and write it to your output file as a single column. Isn't that what you want? Does that not work?

Comment: My English is not good, sorry.

Copy a single column from a file and add it to another pre existing csv file that already contains data (5 columns), So far he is writing further down the existing data and not as a new column

Comment: Ah. Now I understand. Will have another look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately you have to read both files then overwrite your target file.

The reason for this is that files by their very nature can only get more data by adding it to the end of the file. Adding a column will in effect be updating and adding data to many places in the file. In that case the only solution is to read and rewrite the whole file.

As you're aware merging (or concatenating) the files is the way to go: If the ordering of the CSV files is correct, and you don't want to match up rows using a column or index then you can do as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

filenameInp = "filenameInp.csv"
filenameOut = "filenameOut.csv"

input_df = pd.read_csv(filenameInp, delimiter =';', usecols=[5])
output_df = pd.read_csv(filenameOut, delimiter =';', header=None)
output_df = pd.concat([output_df, input_df], axis=1)
output_df.to_csv(filenameOut, sep=';', header=False, index=False)
```

Here we assume there is no header in the target file, and that you don't want to use an index. Just match rows by the order they are presented.

`filenameInp.csv`

```
f; a; b; c; d; e
1;11;12;12;14;15
2;16;17;18;19;20
3;21;22;23;24;25
```

`filenameOut.csv` before running script:

```
1;71;72
2;76;77
3;71;72
```

`filenameOut.csv` after running script:

```
1;71;72;15
2;76;77;20
3;71;72;25
```

Comment: is there any difference between merge, join, or concatenate in pandas?

Comment: @FabioFontes The mainly differ in what style you go about doing it. There is some overlap. I usually go with concat when I just want to stack dataframes together, and merge when I want particular rows to go together. Merge is similar to how you do SQL operations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer